# Problem of display menu until "stop unity-panel-service" command

Tags: unity, gnome

I am new for Ubuntu and gtk+. When I write a sample program to display the menu by gtk, I notice that the menu does not display until I stop the unity-panel-service. It also happen to terminal and File window too. when i type "stop unity-panel-service" the menu buttons of the desktop dis-appear, but the menu of other window show up. Does it is a bug of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or I do something wrong?

Before `stop unity-panel-service`:

[image: before stop unity-panel-service]

After `stop unity-panel-service`:

[image: After stop unity-panel-service]

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour seems to be a wide spread problem introduced with Ubuntu 16.04 and which is not fixed for everyone at this time (2016-12-14).

Check: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bamf/+bug/1532226